# ClassNotFound while using myBatis config

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to connect to DB2 using mybatis. My problem is, mybatis-config is not able to find my class file for the data type I am using.

ClientMapper.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC '-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN'
  'http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd'>

<mapper namespace='Client'> 
    <select id='getNumber' parameterType='String'
        resultType='org.TE1.Client'>
        SELECT
        number AS phone
        FROM client
        WHERE name = #{name}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

ClientMapperInterface.java

```
package org.TE1.Mapper;

public interface ClientMapperInterface {
    public String getNumber(String name);
}
```

Client.java

```
package org.TE1.Client;

public class Client {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;

    //some getters and setters
}
```

mybatis-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC '-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN'
  'http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd'>
<configuration>
    <properties resource='jdbc.properties' />
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias type='org.TE1.Client' alias='Client'></typeAlias>
    </typeAliases>
    <environments default='development'>
        <environment id='development'>
            <transactionManager type='JDBC' />
            <dataSource type='POOLED'>
                <property name='driver' value='com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' />
                <property name='url' value='jdbc:as400://localhost:50000/dir' />
                <property name='username' value='root' />
                <property name='password' value='admin' />
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource='org/TE1/Mapper/ClientMapper.xml' />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

tester java file.

```
public class testGetPhone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis-config.xml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("MyBatis config not found!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();

        int number = session.selectOne("Client.getNumber", "TEST");
        System.out.println("number:" + number);
        session.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

At first I thought there might be something wrong with how the config searches for the class file but after some tinkering I am pretty sure it does find the class file, but thinks its not the correct class file (not sure about it though). Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i changed

```
<typeAlias type='org.TE1.Client' alias='Client'></typeAlias>
```

to

```
<typeAlias type='org.TE1.Client.Client' alias='Client'></typeAlias>
```

and that seemed to do the trick. maybe it really did fail in looking for the class file.

Comment: Indeed, the namespace must be the (full qualified) class name and not just the package name. By the way, it is a best practice to name packages with lower case, and and the fact the last segment of the package path has the same name as the class might have been what created your initial confusion.